# Using doctrines findBy/getBy magic methods with the pager object?

Tags: php, doctrine, pager

Is it possible to use doctrines magic methods (in this case findBy*) with sfDoctrinePager?  I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Doctrine_Collection::offset()
```

Here is the code:

```
$this->pager->setQuery(Doctrine::getTable('notification')->findByUserId($this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId()));
```

I know I can build a query myself just want to know if it's possible using the "magic" methods.

Answer (score 1):

nope, you can't. the findby* methods returns an object or an array of objects. sfDoctrinePager can only work on query objects.